# Можно ли упростить JavaScript код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

```
$(id_form).find('#SuccessData').fadeIn();
$(id_form).find('#InputName').hide();
$(id_form).find('#InputPhone').hide();
$(id_form).find('#InputEmail').hide();
$(id_form).find('#InputFile').hide();
$(id_form).find('#ButtonSubmit').hide();
$(id_form).find('.js-rule-error-req').hide();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вы хотите спрятать все, кроме блока с результатом выполнения Ajax запроса:

```
$(id_form).children().hide();
$('#SuccessData').fadeIn();
```

Если же там много элементов и Вы хотите спрятать именно перечисленные:

```
$('#SuccessData').fadeIn();
$(id_form).find('#InputName, #InputPhone, #InputEmail, #InputFile, #ButtonSubmit, .js-rule-error-req').hide();
```

Обратите внимание, что `.find()` для `#SuccessData` не нужен - id должно быть уникальным на странице, поэтому излишне указывать, что поиск нужно вести только среди потомков `$(id_form)`. И во второй строке он используется только из-за элемента `.js-rule-error-req` - на случай если вруг на странице имеется еще один такой же вне формы.

Comment: "id должно быть уникальным на странице" - вот за это спасибо!